# How to show the Windows Properties dialog in stay-on-top mode?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application, I have a button that shows the Windows Properties dialog of the application when clicked:

```
procedure TformMain.btnShowPropertiesDialogClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowPropertiesDialog(ParamStr(0));
end;

procedure ShowPropertiesDialog(FileName: string);
var
  sei: Winapi.ShellAPI.TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  System.FillChar(sei, SizeOf(sei), 0);
  sei.cbSize := System.SizeOf(sei);
  sei.lpFile := PChar(FileName);
  sei.lpVerb := 'properties';
  sei.fMask  := SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
  Winapi.ShellAPI.ShellExecuteEx(@sei);
end;
```

However, when the app window is in *Stay-On-Top* mode (`Self.FormStyle = fsStayOnTop`), the Windows Properties dialog gets HIDDEN behind the app's window!

Is there a way to show the Windows Properties dialog in *Stay-On-Top* mode?

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Comment: What happens if you provide a parent window handle

Comment: This works as expected: your window stays on top. How about disabling your style while the other window is shown?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `sei.Wnd := formMain.Handle;` does not solve the problem.

Comment: @user1580348 even if it doesn't solve *this* issue, it is still a good thing to do in general, in case `ShellExecuteEx()` needs to display other dialogs of its own. Whenever an API accepts a parent `HWND`, you should always provide one if you have one available.

Comment: If setting Wnd doesn't change the behaviour then I guess you are stuck. Hoist by your own petard.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hoist by Windows' petard.

Comment: Even if you do this the dialog won't necessarily stay on top of your form because the form is itself stay on top. What I mean is the first comment is applicable not only for different programs but also to different windows of the same program.